# Break shell output to files

Tags: java, linux, shell, logging, output

I know I can output script output to a file using :

```
/path/to/script.sh >& path/to/output.log
```

The thing is, I'm making an infinite loop in Java that my shell will run, thus the output file will become extremely large.

Is there anyway using linux commands to break the output by max file size to split the logs or instead i have to change outputin Java instead to console to seperate files by max file size?

Comment: I think this question might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6708580/use-tee-or-equivalent-but-limit-max-file-size-or-rotate-to-new-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something called **[multilog](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/multilog.html)**, try this:

```
/path/to/script.sh |[multilog][2] s2000 ./logdir
```

will run the script capturing stdout to your output.log and rotating it when it is bigger than 2000 bytes.

Comment: And by `rotate` you mean it will change it's name to something else?

Comment: @eric.itzhak Check the link, there is a section for rotated logs.

Comment: @eric.itzhak Yes it will create a new file, read the section "Automatically rotated logs" in the given link.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use [logrotate](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate)

logrotate is designed to ease administration of systems that generate large numbers of log files. It allows automatic rotation, compression, removal, and mailing of log files. Each log file may be handled daily, weekly, monthly, or when it grows too large.