# How to download large csv files from S3 without running into 'out of memory' issue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I need to process large files stored in S3 bucket. I need to divide the csv file into smaller chunks for processing. However, this seems to be a task done better on file-system storage rather an on object storage.
Hence, I am planning to download the large file to local, divide it into smaller chunks and then upload the resultant files together in a different folder. 
I am aware of the method `download_fileobj` but could not determine whether it would result in `out of memory` error while downloading large files of sizes ~= 10GB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend using [`download_file()`](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.download_file):

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.meta.client.download_file('mybucket', 'hello.txt', '/tmp/hello.txt')
```

It will *not* run out of memory while downloading. Boto3 will take care of the transfer process.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `awscli` command line for this. Stream the output as follows:

`aws s3 cp s3://<bucket>/file.txt -`

The above command will stream the file contents in the terminal. Then you can use `split` and/or `tee` commands to create file chunks.

Example: `aws s3 cp s3://<bucket>/file.txt - | split -d -b 100000 -`

More details in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7291791/2732674

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the bandwidth usage by making concurrent S3 API transfer calls

```
        config = TransferConfig(max_concurrency=150)

        s3_client.download_file(
            Bucket=s3_bucket,
            Filename='path',
            Key="key",
            Config=config
        )
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try boto3 [s3.Object](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#object) api.

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
object = s3.Object('bucket_name','key')

body = object.get()['Body'] #body returns streaming string

for line in body:
    print line
```

Comment: That would cause trouble as sometimes in CSV files, in one row there can be newline characters which pandas can take care of but streaming line by line cannot.

Comment: Never encounter such a scenario, I think it could also take for that. Try forming a CSV with this text.
a,b
C \n,d

Comment: Yeah, I faced the issue and hence stating the above experience. The point to be noted is that row != line.