# Cap log file size

Tags: bash, shell, logging, logfile, process-substitution

Say I am writing to a log file:

```
services-manager &> lsm.log
```

is there a program I can use that will cap the log file at a certain size, maybe like 5mb?

so that might look like:

```
services-manager &> <(cap --mb=5 lsm.log)
```

using process substitution or whatever. What it means is if it starts getting too big, it will remove the lines at the beginning of the file.

Comment: Try using tee Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6708580/use-tee-or-equivalent-but-limit-max-file-size-or-rotate-to-new-file

Comment: I don't need to send stdout/stderr to anywhere but the file, so I don't think I need `tee` perse, I just need to write to a program that can delete old data from a file as it writes new data.